# access to protected data member of abstract base class via this->

Tags: c++

I have a problem accesing protected data members of an abstract base class. Say I have the following structure:

```
class A {
   public:
       //func_xy()=0;  
       //...
   protected:
       int id;
       //...
};
```

Now I inherit from the abstract base class A:

```
class B: public A {
    public:
        func_xy();

        //...
    private:
        void func_b();
        std::vector<A*> vec_a;
        //...
};    

//...

void B::func_b() {

    A& _a = *vec_a[0];
    //doesn't work, class A has no member named ‘_a‘...
    int id1 = this->_a.id;
    //doesn't work, expected unqualified-id before ‘(’...
    int id2 = this->(_a.id);
}
```

If I`m using a pointer instead of a reference the problem remains.
Is there any trick to get the protected data member?

Comment: Replace `this->_a.id` with `_a.id`. Note that `_a` is a local variable, not a class member.

Comment: Doesn`t work unfortunately, as Martin pointed out

Comment: Add `public: A::get_id() {return id;}`

Answer (score 3):

Once you have fixed the compilation error by changing

```
    int id1 = this->_a.id;
```

to

```
    int id1 = _a.id;
```

You will find it still doesn't work.  The problem is that `_a` is an `A`, not a `B`.  As a member function of `B` you only get access to protected members of `A` when they are bases of `B`.

So, you can easily access `this->id` - but you can't get at the `id` of `_a`.

You need:

```
class B: public A {
    public:
        func_xy();

        //...
    private:
        void func_b();
        std::vector<B*> vec_b;
        //...
};    

//...

void B::func_b() {

    B& _b = *vec_b[0];
    int id1 = _b.id;  // OK.  Not only can you touch this->id, you can
                      // touch the id of *any* B.
}
```

Comment: ...
Once you have fixed the compilation error by changing

    int id1 = this->_a.id;

to

    int id1 = _a.id;

You will find it still doesn't work.
...

Yep, I knew this. Your solution might work, but the problem for me is, that it isn`t clear at compile time what objects hide behind task. That is objects pointed to by the vector pointers can be objects from two derived task classes (in my application).
So there is no possibility to get to id , without dynamic cast which would be ugly imo?

Comment: Can you make both classes derive from B?  Can you give A a read-only getter?  (or even a setter if necessary).

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake in my code snippet above. See my next post for the updated version.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/508/classes-structures/7872/friendship#t=201608291514107565524